# For Loop for specific numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to write a for loop such that it only contains numbers between 1 and 7 (both inclusive) and the numbers get stored in a list. 
The length of the list should be 8629.
This is the code which i try to run. I get this error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
random_list = []
 for i in range(0,8628):
 x = i % 7
 random_list[i].append(x+1)
 while i == i + 1

print(random_list)
```

Comment: In Python, incorrect indentation is considered a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your requirement is : 
The length of the list should be 8629 and write a for loop such that it only contains numbers between 1 and 7. shouldn't it be like this?

```
from random import *
random_list = []
while len(random_list) < 5:
    random_list.append(randint(1, 7))

print(random_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help this works :). However, what should i do, if i want to store these numbers in the list as a string and not as a number

Comment: `str(randint(1, 7))`

Comment: welcome and as @f5r5e5d mentioned replace 
random_list.append(randint(1, 7)) with random_list.append( str( randint(1, 7) ) )

Answer (score 0):

This will give random integers in the range you specified:

**Code**

```
import random


random_list = [random.randint(1, 7) for _ in range(8629)]
```

**Test**

```
random_list[:10]
# [3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 1, 3, 7, 7, 6]
min(random_list), max(random_list)
# (1, 7)
len(random_list)
# 8629
```

---

For a cycle of consecutive numbers, try `itertools`:

**Code**

```
import itertools as it


cycled_list = list(it.islice(it.cycle(range(1, 8)), 8629))
```

**Test**

```
cycled_list[:10]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3]
min(cycled_list), max(cycled_list)
# (1, 7)
len(cycled_list)
# 8629
```

See @Ming Chu's post for list compression variant.

Answer (score 0):

```
random_list = [i % 7 + 1 for i in range(8628)]
print(random_list)
```

The list will be :[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...........]

Comment: `[i % 7 + 1 for i in range(8629)]` gives the right length.

Comment: Thank you for the help this works :). However, what should i do, if i want to store these numbers in the list as a string and not as a number –

Comment: you mean is string type not int?
`[ str( i % 7+ 1 ) for i in range(8629)]`